# detailTextLabel isn't displayed but 100% set

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I have an [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell) added in my tableView like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as! MGSwipeTableCell!
    if cell == nil {

        cell = MGSwipeTableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.backgroundColor = blue
}
```

All works fine. But now If I tap the cell the color of the cell changes for maybe a second to white and then to green (default color is blue). This is what should happen if the cell has been pressed:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  let mySelectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MGSwipeTableCell!
  mySelectedCell.backgroundColor = green
  mySelectedCell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Test" 
}
```

So the color should only change to green not to white and then to green and a detailTextLabel with the text "Test" should be displayed. 
I hope you can help me to solve this problem. I don't really know what to do.

Solution:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as! MGSwipeTableCell!
    cell = MGSwipeTableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,  reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.backgroundColor = blue

}
```

Comment: Where and how you create `mySelectedCell` object that you use in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`?

Comment: UITableViewCellStyle.Default does not have a subtitle. You have to use .Value1, .Value2, or .Subtitle depending on how you want your cell to look.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellStyle

Comment: @alex_p It was my fault I should be cell instead of mySelectedCell. I updated the question.

Comment: @Tyrelidrel Didn't helped. I tried all the 3 Styles it's still not working.

Comment: What value of `Selection` field for you custom cell in `Attributes inspector` in storyboard?

Comment: The selection is set to default.

Comment: Try set to `None` It looks like the cell is selected and then drop it

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as! MGSwipeTableCell!
if cell == nil {
    //Change this line
    cell = MGSwipeTableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
//And this line
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
cell.delegate = self
cell.backgroundColor = blue
}
```

leave everything as is inside "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Now the change of the colors works but the detailTextLabel is still not displayed.

Comment: in "didSelectRowAtIndexPath", can u put a breakpoint after "mySelectedCell.backgroundColor = green" and then in the console "po mySelectedCell.detailedTextLabel"?

Comment: I solved it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function (see my question). Thanks for your help!

Comment: perfect, no problem :D